# How to expand quadratic equations in Octave/Matlab?

Tags: polynomials, matlab, computer-algebra-systems

I have some column vectors, and I put them in a row, so I have $[a \, b \, c]$. Now I want to get a matrix of the form $[a^2 \, b^2 \, c^2 \, ab \, ac \, bc]$. It is like expanding $(a+b+c)^2$, but applying it to matrix columns. Is there any trick in Octave/Matlab that would allow me to do it automatically? The example is easy. Imagine if I want to get $[a_1 \, a_2 \, \cdots a_n]$ to a higher degree. It would be a pain to do it manually.

Comment: Are these numeric or symbolic vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polynomial multiplication [is equivalent to convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22844/why-is-polynomial-convolution-equivalent-to-multiplication-in-fx-xn-1). This means that if you have two numeric vectors, you can use the [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) function in Matlab:

```
v1 = [2 3 4];
v2 = [3 5 7];
w = conv(v1,v2)
```

which returns

```
w =

     6    19    41    41    28
```

The vectors don't even need to be the same length. In your case, you can just pass the same vector in twice.

Unfortunately, the `conv` function isn't overloaded for symbolic variables. Howver, you can take advantage of [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html)'s [polynomial capabilities](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/polynomial-algebra.html) from [within Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html) (I have no idea what Octave supports in this area). You can use [`poly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/poly.html) to create polynomials from coefficients. These objects can be multiplied together naturally. Then you can use [`coeff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/coeff.html) to extract the symbolic coefficients. Here's an example:

```
syms a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2;
v1 = char([a1 b1 c1]);
p1 = feval(symengine,'poly',v1(9:end-2),'[x]');
v2 = char([a2 b2 c2]);
p2 = feval(symengine,'poly',v2(9:end-2),'[x]');
w = feval(symengine,'coeff',p1*p2)
```

which returns the symbolic vector:

```
w =

[ c1*c2, b1*c2 + b2*c1, a1*c2 + a2*c1 + b1*b2, a1*b2 + a2*b1, a1*a2]
```