# Why is polynomial convolution equivalent to multiplication in F[x]/(xn−1)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, convolution

[Why is polynomial convolution equivalent to multiplication in $F[x]/(x^n-1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22844/why-is-polynomial-convolution-equivalent-to-multiplication-in-fx-xn-1)

From this, I still can not understand how to get this
$$
\begin{align}
&f*g +(x^n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i+j=k+n}f_ig_jx^k
\end{align}
$$

from 
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i+j=k}f_ig_j+\sum_{i+j=k+n}f_ig_jx^n\right)x^k\\
\end{align}
$$

Thanks for answers.