# Proof that convolution of polynomials congruent to multiplication of polynomials modulo $(x^n)-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis

I wanted to show the relation between convolution and polynomial multiplication like it is showed [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS424/Lectures/FastMultiplication.html/node4.html). I saw in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22848/353199) thread a similar approach to mine but with same degrees for both polynomials. So what I try to show is that 
$$p*q \equiv pq \mod x^{n}-1 $$
but I don't really know how I can continue my calculation to get to this form (but I don't really get this form like in the threads I linked).

$
p(x)q(x) = \\ \sum_{k=0}^{m+n}(\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j}b_{j})x^k = \\ \sum_{k=0}^{m}(\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j}b_{j})x^k + \sum_{k=m}^{m+n}(\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j}b_{j})x^k = \\ \sum_{k=0}^{m}(\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j}b_{j})x^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n}(\sum_{j=m}^{k+m} a_{k-j+m}b_{j-m})x^{k+m} = \\ \sum_{k=0}^{m}(\sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j}b_{j})x^k + x^m(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\sum_{j=m}^{k+m} a_{k-j+m}b_{j-m})x^{k}+x^{n}\sum_{j=m}^{n+m}a_{n-j+m}b_{j-m}) 
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pad the coefficients with zeroes. You should be aware that you need to do this to even define the convolution due to the $a_{k-j}$ terms in your sum. That is, if $\deg f = N$ and $ \deg g = N+M$, then write $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^Na_n x^n + \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+M} 0x^n$ and use the known result.

Comment: So if I have two polynomials one with degree m and the other with degree n, then I should pad the coefficients of the smaller degree polynomial with zeros until it matches the degree of the other polynomial, right?

Comment: @mannequin that's right.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have a question about the known result, because I don't see how the person gets $(x^n)-1$ i the last line. I get $x^n$ instead.

Comment: @mannequin the left term is not exactly $f*g$, which is why you don't just take out the right term (which gives you $x^n$). You need to add and subtract $∑_{i+j = k+n} f_i g_j $.